# Definition of "essential limit sup"?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the article of Lions https://www.jstor.org/stable/2045002?seq=1 the following notion is used:
$$L=\underset{y \to x_0}{\text{lim sup ess }} f(y),$$
for a measurable function $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ but I have no idea what it means.

- What is the precise definition of this $L$ with quantifiers ?
- How to pronounce it, is it "essential supremum limit" ?
- Where to find it in classical textbooks ?
- I have also seen "$\text{ess lim sup }$" in another article, is it the same object ?

Comment: Yes, French "lim sup ess" is the same as English "ess lim sup".  In French, an adjective is usually placed after the noun it modifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L$ is defined by the following properties:

a) For every $\epsilon >0$ ther exist $\delta >0$ such that $|y-x_0| <\delta$ implies $f(x) \leq L+\epsilon$ almost everywhere.

b) No smaller number has property a).

'ess lim  sup' is same as 'lim sup ess'.

You pronounce it as 'essential lim sup' (or eseential limit superior).

Comment: Thanks ! So it is the same as $\inf_{\delta>0} (\text{ess sup} \{f(x) \quad | \quad |x-x_0|<\delta\})$ ?

Comment: @perturbation Yes, that is correct.